# How to insert a beautified JSON string into table cell in a Word document using Open XML

Tags: c#, json, openxml

I am generating a Word document with Open XML.  The document includes a table, and some of the cells contain a JSON string.

Before inserting the JSON string I beautify it with the following lines:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken parsedJson = 
      Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.JToken.Parse(unformattedJsonString);

string formattedJsonString = parsedJson.ToString(Formatting.Indented);
```

For my OpenXML code I started with the "Reflect Code" from the OpenXML SDK 2.5.  It looks like this:

```
TableCell tableCell2 = new TableCell();

TableCellProperties tableCellProperties2 = new TableCellProperties();
TableCellWidth tableCellWidth2 = new TableCellWidth() { Width = "8640", Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa };
Shading shading2 = new Shading() { Val = ShadingPatternValues.Clear, Color = "auto", Fill = "auto" };

tableCellProperties2.Append(tableCellWidth2);
tableCellProperties2.Append(shading2);

Paragraph paragraph2 = new Paragraph() { RsidParagraphAddition = "00006AF4", RsidParagraphProperties = "00006AF4", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00006AF4" };

ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties2 = new ParagraphProperties();
SpacingBetweenLines spacingBetweenLines2 = new SpacingBetweenLines() { After = "0" };

paragraphProperties2.Append(spacingBetweenLines2);

Run run2 = new Run();

Text textSecondColumn = new Text();
textSecondColumn.Text = formattedJsonString;  // see the snippet above

run2.Append(textSecondColumn);

paragraph2.Append(paragraphProperties2);
paragraph2.Append(run2);

tableCell2.Append(tableCellProperties2);
tableCell2.Append(paragraph2);

tableRow.Append(tablePropertyExceptions);
tableRow.Append(tableCell1);
tableRow.Append(tableCell2);
```

So here's the problem - even though the string "formattedJsonString" is definitely beautified, all the line breaks and indents are lost in the final document.

I used to do this in Word Interop and it worked fine.  Any idea for how to handle this with Open XML?

By the way - The SDK will not open a document.xml that has formatted/beautified Json text.

Amendment: It just occurred to me that the formatting adds line breaks - and that perhaps each line needs to be a separate paragraph.  Gonna try that and will amend this post again if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.  You do need to convert the line breaks, but I don't think each line needs to be a separate paragraph (although I suppose you could do it that way if you wanted to).  I would instead just create a `Run` for each line, inserting a `Break` element before the `Text` element in each one except the first.  Also be sure to set the `Space` property on each `Text` element to `SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve` to ensure the leading whitespace isn't lost.
Add all the `Runs` to the `Paragraph` inside the `TableCell` and that should do it.

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
static void AddJsonToParagraph(string json, Paragraph paragraph)
{
    string[] lines = json.Split(Environment.NewLine);
    bool isFirstLine = true;

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        Run run = new Run();

        if (!isFirstLine)
        {
            run.Append(new Break());
        }
        isFirstLine = false;

        Text text = new Text
        {
            Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve,
            Text = line
        };
        run.Append(text);
        paragraph.Append(run);
    }
}
```

In your code, replace the line that appends `run2` to `paragraph2` with this:

```
AddJsonToParagraph(formattedJsonString, paragraph2);
```

Comment: Brian - awesome!  Thanks.  I especially appreciate you noting the SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve value - which makes a huge difference of course.   One of the side benefits here is that the line count allows me to estimate how many pages a large json will will use. This is important to me because I merge a bunch of these documents together and find that i need to limit the merged document to around 10,000 pages - or they become difficult for my end users to use without having word hang or crash.

Comment: No problem; glad I could help!